# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v4.view.ViewGroupCompat.getLayoutMode

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, android-gridview

Hi there i have been using viewpager and android native gridview controller for a GridViewLayout to show images, i have been working on 4.0 and up devices for so long and supporting the supported with the libraries provided

when i come to 2.3 devices later in gingerbread series the GridViewLayout gave nosuch class found and so i have included v7 gridlayout library and started converting code upon to it

from the on i am getting the following issue -

```
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v4.view.ViewGroupCompat.getLayoutMode
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Bounds.include(GridLayout.java:2262)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis.computeGroupBounds(GridLayout.java:1206)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis.getGroupBounds(GridLayout.java:1215)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis.createLinks(GridLayout.java:1224)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis.getForwardLinks(GridLayout.java:1250)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis.createArcs(GridLayout.java:1375)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis.getArcs(GridLayout.java:1408)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis.solve(GridLayout.java:1579)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis.computeLocations(GridLayout.java:1662)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis.getLocations(GridLayout.java:1686)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis.getMeasure(GridLayout.java:1707)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis.getMeasure(GridLayout.java:1718)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.onMeasure(GridLayout.java:952)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8366)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8366)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8366)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.widget.ListView.measureScrapChild(ListView.java:1178)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1243)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1152)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8366)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8366)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8366)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8366)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8366)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8366)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:847)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1868)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3693)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
04-17 10:08:59.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

[image: Order and export tab]

MinSDK - 7 and TargetSDK - 18

Comment: Please post the screenshot of your project's properties where you have added the library in your build path.

Comment: I have added the screen shot of order and export tab

Comment: Make sure that you are using the correct(latest) version of the v4 support library.You might be using older v4 support library ( which lacks this API 18 method ).